# Get consumers for routing key when using wildcards

Tags: rabbitmq

Is it possible to get a list of consumers for a particular routing key when using wildcards?

I have two consumers creating these two routing keys:

```
customer.created.#
customer.created.from.template.#
```

I want to find out which routing keys match for a `customer.created.from.template` event.

Comment: Essentially if i understand your question correctly , you would like to know which route the message has taken to land up in the queue. Am i correct in my understanding.

Comment: It is more about to know from a publishers perspective which subscribers will receive a message.

Comment: The real question is "why would you ever need this?" When sending a message, it is generally not possible to know if or when it will ever be received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RabbitMQ has a [management API](https://pulse.mozilla.org/api/). One of the methods you can call on this is the `/consumers` endpoint, which will list all consumers on a particular RabbitMQ cluster.

While I'm sure there would be a way to use this information to get what you need here, I'm not sure what the particular use case is. If you could supply additional detail, it might be possible to advise further.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way of doing this is by the use of **[Firehose Tracer](https://www.rabbitmq.com/firehose.html)**.

The firehose publishes messages to the topic exchange amq.rabbitmq.trace. In this section we refer to the messages consumed and inspected via the Firehose mechanism as "traced messages".

Traced message routing key will be either "**publish.{exchangename}**" (for messages entering the node), or "**deliver.{queuename}**" (for messages that are delivered to consumers).

[image]

The Trace queue can then be consumed to extract the desired information.